# Modify a Windows install disc

Tags: windows, backup, installation

Is it possible to modify an XP (Or maybe even Windows 7, if I find some cash) disc so that when I install it, it will install other files (Or even just carry the executable/setup files for them) so that i don't have to?

Essentially, I'd like to have a backup disc of XP that I can use on other computers (I have more than one key, of course), that I can use to install XP, with all the current updates/service packs, and some other software I frequently always add anyway (Avira, Malware-Bytes, Daemon-Tools, etc.) without me needing to go through hours of installs because my XP disc currently doesn't even have SP1.

Is it possible?

Also... I'm not sure if I should make this another question altogether, but I have a few friends that are on the Windows98 - XP upgrade as well, and I'm wondering if it's also possible to store the Windows 98 disc on the XP disc so and get it to find the files on the 98 disc while installing...

All of these steps would save me MASSIVE amounts of time.

**EDIT:** Found how to add all the service packs and updates using [nlite](http://www.nliteos.com) (or [AutoStreamer](http://majorgeeks.com/AutoStreamer%5Fd4444.html)), but am still wondering if there is a way to add executable/setup files for unrelated programs to the install disc, and whether or not it's possible to add the required windows 98 files (or the full disc) to an upgrade disc (though the upgrade one isn't very important).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com/)! It can integrate any updates you want after you download them:

[image]

Guide found [here](http://www.nliteos.com/guide/index.html).

Comment: Simply amazing. I'm definitely going to try that.

Comment: i vote for nlite as well. You can also remove a massive amount of unused features using this disk.

Answer (score 1):

**[AutoStreamer](http://majorgeeks.com/AutoStreamer_d4444.html)** is a easy and quick slipstreamer for Windows Operating Systems.

[image]

Here's a **[tutorial](http://www.webtree.ca/windowsxp/slipstream.htm)** that explains how to add additional installers to your installaion CD/DVD

*If you can find the cash, then use **[vLite](http://www.vlite.net/)** for Windows Vista/7.*

Comment: Does vLite work for Windows 7? It looks like it's only for Vista.

Comment: yes, it does. if you need some ideas, google for: vlite session.ini windows 7

Comment: Thanks! At least when Windows 7 comes out I won't be stuck doing the same thing again. Sucks being the only technical person you know. Thanks again Molly!